# Use of iret when returning from exec system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I noticed that at the end of the `start_thread` function, which is called after most of the work of `exec` is done, there is a call to `force_iret`:

```
    static void
    start_thread_common(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long new_ip,
        unsigned long new_sp,
        unsigned int _cs, unsigned int _ss, unsigned int _ds)
    {
         loadsegment(fs, 0);
         loadsegment(es, _ds);
         loadsegment(ds, _ds);
         load_gs_index(0);
         regs->ip       = new_ip;
         regs->sp       = new_sp;
         regs->cs       = _cs;
         regs->ss       = _ss;
         regs->flags        = X86_EFLAGS_IF;
         force_iret();
    }
```

I presume that this is done to ensure that that `sysexit` is not used to return to user space. So why does `iret` have to be used when returning from `exec`?

Comment: You should probably do some research about what `iret` does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I've a pretty good idea of what `iret` does. I just can't understand why `iret` has to be used instead of `sysexit` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function modifies registers that `sysret`/`sysexit` would not restore.

Here's `arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h`:

```
/*
 * Force syscall return via IRET by making it look as if there was
 * some work pending. IRET is our most capable (but slowest) syscall
 * return path, which is able to restore modified SS, CS and certain
 * EFLAGS values that other (fast) syscall return instructions
 * are not able to restore properly.
 */
#define force_iret() set_thread_flag(TIF_NOTIFY_RESUME)
```